# split creation date into two string

Tags: javascript, css, json, vue.js

Is it possible to split this string into two

using css or another way?

```
<p>30/10/2018 16:10</p>
```

into

```
<p>30/10/2018</p>
<p>16:10</p>
```

because i have a string data from JSON API that return value like "30/10/2018 16:10" by using this code `<p>{{creationDate}}</p>`

but I needed it to display like this

30/10/2018

16:10

Did anyone get any idea for how to settle this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the date with space character which will give you the the date in `0` index and the time in `1` index:

```
<p>{{creationDate.split(' ')[0]}}</p>
<p>{{creationDate.split(' ')[1]}}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use moment for date format

```
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.filter('formatDate', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    return moment(String(value)).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
  }
}
Vue.filter('formatTime', function(value) {
  if (value) {
    return moment(String(value)).format('hh:mm')
  }
}
<P>{{yourDateString | formatDate}}</P>
<P>{{yourDateString | formatTime}}</P>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript split function. Use space as separator.

Syntax: ***string.split(separator, limit)***

Read more: *https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp*

```js
let creationDate="30/10/2018 16:10";
creationDate=creationDate.split(' ');
const docum=document.getElementById("date");
docum.innerHTML='<p>'+creationDate[0]+'</p>'+'<p>'+creationDate[1]+'</p>';
```

```html
<div id="date"></div>
```